# c++ extract an int from inside a string using stringstream

Tags: c++, stringstream

So I have the following string, `line` is it possible to extract the int that's inside?

I can use a very rudimentary regex expression but some stringstream solutions I found here look way cleaner and convert to type int.

```
string line = "            <li id="episode_275">"
```

I have the following code, but I don't know to deal with the rest of the string like: the 4 tab indent,the "

```
int value;
stringstream ss(line);
ss >> value;
```

Comment: Probably more a job for `std..regex` and `std::stoi` for the match.

Comment: @πάνταῥεῖ I guess it's just too complex for stringstream right?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This can be done quite simply by just looking for the first digit, then having `strtol` do the integer parsing for you from that point:

```
#include <string>
#include <cctype>
#include <cstdlib>

int extractFirstIntInString(std::string const& s)
{
    for (std::size_t i = 0; i != s.size(); ++i)
        if (std::isdigit(s[i]))
            return std::strtol(s.c_str() + i, nullptr, 10);
    return 0;    // no integer in string
}
```